# How to fopen a file in a different location?

Tags: c, fopen

I'm trying to open a file that is located in a different directory, but I always get the error message. My code looks like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>   
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
  {
  FILE *file;
  char file_name[25];

  printf("What file do you want? ");
  scanf("%s", file_name);
  file = fopen("Dir1/Dir2/file_name","r"); 

  if( file == NULL ) 
  {
    printf("There is no file by that name\n");
    exit;
 }
```

I suspect that the problem is due to the "fopen" part.  If I type in a filename name (ex. file =fopen ("Dir1/Dir2/list.txt", "r") then it will work.  However, I want the user to input the filename.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: You make a very fundamental mistake when dealing with user input: If you don't know the length of what is entered (and you never know what the user does), put a hard limit on it.
You can do so with `fgets()` instead of `scanf()`, or you can use a safe `scanf` format string such as `%24s`.

Comment: Note: File names may include spaces.  `scanf("%s", file_name)` will not scan those into `file_name`.  Consider `scanf("%24[\^n]", file_name)` or `fgets()`.

Answer (score 1):

Your code tries to open the file named "file_name". I suppose you mean this:

```
#include <stdio.h>   
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
  FILE *file;
  char file_name[25];
  char path[80];

  printf("What file do you want? ");
  scanf("%s", file_name);
  snprintf(path, sizeof(path), "Dir1/Dir2/%s", file_name);
  // printf("Opening file %s\n", path);
  file = fopen(path,"r"); 

  if( file == NULL ) 
  {
    printf("There is no file by that name\n");
    exit;
  }
```

Comment: Your answer would be worth a +1, if you didn't use `sprintf()` for dealing with user input. What if the user enters a string with more than 80 characters? (Ok, before this has an impact on `path`, `file_name` will overflow. But that would be worth mentioning.)`

Comment: You're absolutely right, but since the asker uses scanf, I guessed overruns weren't the main concern. Will edit though.

Comment: Overruns are always a concern IMHO - it is always better to teach beginners the right thing as early as possible.

Comment: In this particular case, `sprintf()` is indeed safe, as 80 >> 25 + the path bytes, but nevertheless it would be better to get used to `snprintf(path, sizeof path, ...)`. So +1 :-)